# LibJWT produce lib SSL error 0906D06C

Tags: c++, ssl, arm, embedded, jwt

I use the [JWT CPP lib](https://github.com/pokowaka/jwt-cpp) for an embedded project on an ARMV7.

Here is my code so far:

```
  // Reading the private key file                                                                                                                             
  std::ifstream ifs("config/rsa_private.pem");
  std::string key((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
                  (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

  std::cout << key.c_str() << std::endl;

  // Validate private key with RS256 encryption                                                                                                               
  RS256Validator signer(key.c_str());

  // About expiration time                                                                                                                                    
  std::time_t iat = std::time(nullptr);

  std::tm expiration_date = *std::localtime(&iat);
  expiration_date.tm_year += 1;

  std::time_t exp = mktime(&expiration_date);

  // Creating the json payload that expires 1 year from today                                                                                                 
  json_ptr json(json_pack("iat", iat, "exp", exp, "aud", CLOUD_PROJECT_ID));

  // Let's encode the token to a char[]                                                                                                                       
  _jwt.reset(JWT::Encode(&signer, json.get()));

  std::cout << "GENERATED TOKEN:" << _jwt.get() << std::endl;
```

When I create my RS256Validator object, the program crash with the folowing error:

> error:0906D06C:lib(9):func(109):reason(108)

After some research, I found out that it is related to the `LibSSL` and that it is mostly that the parameter (the key) is invalid. I am supposed to give the private key and not the public one and it seems to be perfectly valid so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

The embedded board is a MangOH Green running Legato.